# Edit default Wordpress password reset email

Tags: php, wordpress

So I first tried using the [retrieve_password_message](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/retrieve_password_message/) filter, but unfortunately I got no response when entering the email on the site and no email was being sent. (btw I am using the OceanWP Popup Login)

```
add_filter( 'retrieve_password_message', 'my_retrieve_password_message', 10, 4 );

function my_retrieve_password_message( $message, $key, $user_login, $user_data ) {

    $site_name = wp_specialchars_decode( get_option( 'blogname' ), ENT_QUOTES );
    $message = __( 'Die Passwortzurücksetzung wurde für das folgende Konto beantragt:' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    /* translators: %s: site name */
    $message .= sprintf( __( 'Name der Website: %s' ), $site_name ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    /* translators: %s: user login */
    $message .= sprintf( __( 'Username: %s' ), $user_login ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __( 'Wenn dies ein Fehler war, ignorieren Sie diese E-Mail einfach, und es wird nichts passieren.' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __( 'Um Ihr Passwort zurückzusetzen, besuchen Sie die folgende Adresse:' ) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= '<https://smartinvestor.de/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=' . $key . '&login=' . rawurlencode( $user_login) . ">\r\n";

    return $message;

}
```

I had a feeling that it had to do with the $user_login. So I then attempted to reconstruct the data from the filter. Now the user gets a response and the email sends (which I was not getting with the above code), but unfortunately there seems to be a problem with the login. $user_login is not working, it is just being returned blank, meaning the password reset url is not working.

If I enter the login manually the url works, confirming it is not to do with the key. My theory is that because the username is not the trimmed email, that it is returning false? How can I get the user_login without getting it from the email.

```
add_filter('retrieve_password_message', 'my_reset_password_message', null, 2);

function my_reset_password_message( $message, $key ) {

    if ( strpos($_POST['user_login'], '@') ) {
        $user_data = get_user_by('email', trim($_POST['user_login']));
    } else {
        $login = trim($_POST['user_login']);
        $user_data = get_user_by('login', $login);
    }

    $user_login = $user_data->user_login;

    $msg = __('The password for the following account has been requested to be reset:'). "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= network_site_url() . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __('If this message was sent in error, please ignore this email.') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $msg .= __('To reset your password, visit the following address:');
    $msg .= network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login');


    return $msg;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use the user_login provided by the hook it self, try like this.

```
add_filter("retrieve_password_message", "my_reset_password_message", 99, 4);

function my_reset_password_message($message, $key, $user_login, $user_data )    {

    $message = "The password for the following account has been requested to be reset:

    " . sprintf(__('%s'), $user_data->user_email) . "

    If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.

    To reset your password, visit the following address:

    " . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login), 'login') . "\r\n";

    return $message;

}
```

I ckecked the reset mail form you are using on your site. For username/email field u are using "opl_user_or_email" instead of "user_login" hence the user_login field is coming empty, you can either change the form and replace "opl_user_or_email" to "user_login" which I would recommend or you can replace $_POST["user_login"] in your 2nd approach with $_POST["opl_user_or_email"].

[image]

Comment: thats what I tried initially, but it doesnt work. The email doesnt even send if that function is inserted, thats why I tried the work around.

Comment: Can you try putting the exact message and not the message u have added in the first approach? just verify if it's not a problem with your message.

Comment: Ok. Try trim( wp_unslash( $_POST['user_login'] ) ) instead of trim( $_POST['user_login'] ) in your second approach. Also make sure the username or email you are requesting reset password for is actually a user on the site.

Comment: the email is sending so it must be finding the email, but the user name is still missing from both sections:
''' $msg .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";""
"" . rawurlencode($user_login) ""

Comment: Can u give any other info about your setup and where are u writing this piece of code b/c I tried both of the above approaches and both of them are working?

Comment: this is currently running on the website https://smartinvestor.de and adding the code to the child theme's functions.php

Comment: Check out my edit, it's a problem with your reset password form. The fixes I have recommended should solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem. Been trying to find a solution to this for a while.

Comment: No worries. Happy to help.